# Play sound while mouse1 is pressed, stop sound when unpressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding in Unity and basicly I have a character with a spray can. When I hold in the mouse1 button I want my "Spraycan" to sound.

I have tried it in an void update and then I get multiple of the same sound stacked on each other.

```
void Update()
   {
       if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
       {
           FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Spraycan");
       }
       else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
       {
           //STOP SOUND HERE
       }
   }
```

EDIT: My AudioManager is completly ripped off Brackeys tutorial and looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;

    public static AudioManager instance;


    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;


            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Play("Theme");
    }


    public void Play (string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        if (s == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Sound: " + name + "not found!");
            return;
        }

        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you try?  other than making the if statements, what have you tried to stop it?

Comment: I am completly new to C# so the onlything i tried instead of "//STOP SOUND HERE" is "return;". That did not work obviosly

Comment: no return just exits that function ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should define a stop method in your `AudioManager` class. Something like this (NOT TESTED):

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;

    public static AudioManager instance;

    void Awake() { ... }
    void Start() { ... }

    public void Play(string name) { ... }

    public void Stop(string name) {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        if (s == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Sound: " + name + "not found!");
            return;
        }

        s.source.Stop();
    }
}
```

And then implement it as such:

```
void Update()
{
    //Get Button will fire this continuously as you keep it pressed. 
    //Consider using GetButtonDown, or implement delayed repetition.
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Spraycan");
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
    {
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Stop("Spraycan");
    }
}
```

Side note: There are things in your code that are working against efficiency:

- If you use a `Dictionary` instead of an `Array` for your sounds, your lookup will be much faster.
- Assign `FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>()` to a variable at `Start()` and avoid constantly looking it up as the user presses the mouse button.

I won't go into too much detail as it's unrelated to the question.

Side note 2: I completely agree with BugFinder's answer. To become a better programmer, you should slowly start to learn how to navigate through the API documentation and find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this answere. I implemented everything and I do not get any error, but the sound do not go off.

Comment: And to clarify, I also 100% agree to find an solution before posting it here on SO. I just started doing this and I have come far with my project even tho with no prior experience with any coding. This had me stuck for the entire day and I cant continue without this problem solved

Comment: Oh it works! I made a small error. Thank  you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Sam,

half the key of programming is learning how to find things.

If you look at the unity manual on audiosource https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html

You will see where brackeys "play" came from.. and look what else is there..  What do you see that sounds remarkably like it stops the source playing?

See if you can make your own stop function for that..

Comment: I am sure I need to change the void OnGUI, but I really cant see how to.. C# and Unity is brand new for me

Comment: nope the update you had was fine.. you just need to add a little to the audio manager with the hints from above

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("fire1")
    AudioManager.Play

if (Input.GetButtonUp("fire1")
    AudioManager.Stop
```

That AudioManager must have a Stop() method. that calls the .Stop() method of the AudioSource. If it doesn't, create it.

Comment: Please see my EDIT!

Answer (score -2):

The Update function will fire almost continuously, like every frame or something (I do not remember its interval)
You have to use an event specific to the button when it is pressed down.
Then use a flag to indicate that the sound is currently playing in order to not start another playback.
When the playback is down, start it over.
Until the user release the button, then you sent the flag to false and stop the sound.